# VS 2008 (C#) - class outline view?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am new to .NET and VS development so I was wondering if there is a "class outline" window in VS as well (like eclipse). I have this very very long class and I don't want to scroll through it, so I'd like to have a view with the class summary of the open source code (like its members, methods, etc) so that I can juts click to the method or property that I want. Is there a view like this in VS 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as eclipse.

But you have two combo at the top of the code window. The left combo permit you to select object and controls you're using while the right combo will show you a list of properties/methods/events that your class has in alphabetical order.

Like in the following screenshot (taken from VS2010 but is almost the same)

[image]

You can distinguish properties from methods by its icon.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, it was in front of my all this time

Answer (score 1):

Use `Class Diagram` or `Class view` to see what you are looking for.
For `Class View`: View -> Class View
For `Class Diagram`: Project -> Add new item -> ClassDiagram
Good luck

Comment: I tried this already but didn't get what I wanted though. But thanks anyway